# Trying to control temperature of hotend using PWM signal and MOSFET

Tags: pla, diy-3d-printer, hotend, fdm

I have a 40 W, 12 V resistance heater in the hotend. It also has a 100 kΩ thermistor built in. I am using an Arduino to read the temperature on the LCD. This is working fine.

I want to use this temperature using a MOSFET and the PWM signal that is generated by the ARDUINO.
So I connected the PWM signal to the Gate of the MOSFET and connected the 12 V, 3 A supply to the drain of the MOSFET. And connected the Resistance heater of the 3D printer to the source and ground.

But the problem that I am facing is that the Current is flowing from drain and the source even without the gate signal to the MOSFET.

I am not able to control the current to the resistance heater.

Mosfet: IRFZ44N
and the AC to DC adapter is 12 V, 3 A.
PWM signal is max 2 V.

Comment: please add a wiring diagram

Comment: As a side note, 12V at 3A is only 36W. Using that with a 40W heater is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

> connected the 12 V, 3 A supply to the drain of the MOSFET. And connected the Resistance heater of the 3D printer to the source and ground.

The MOSFET is damaged. If the gate is at $0V$, no current should be able to flow.

You're trying to use an N-channel MOSFET as a high-side switch. This is a bad idea, because it would require more than $12V$ at the gate to turn the MOSFET on properly. It would be better to set this up as a low-side switch so that the microcontroller can drive the gate directly. The MOSFET should go between the load and ground, not between the load and $+12V$.

The fact that you connected it like this is the very reason the MOSFET has been damaged. When the MOSFET is OFF, there is $0V$ across the heater. When the microcontroller starts to turn the MOSFET ON (by applying $5V$ to the gate, thus increasing $V_{GS}$ to above $V_{th}$), current starts to flow through the load and the voltage across the load increases. This in turn decreases $V_{GS}$, causing the MOSFET to turn off. You will end up with approximately $3V$ across the load and $V_{GS}=2V$. You've got $9V$ being dropped across your MOSFET and with a current of approximately $800mA$, the $7W$ of heat produced will quickly kill the MOSFET.